# Prove that there exists $a\in \mathbb{C}$ such as $B=(1-a)A+aC$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let A,B and C be three distinct matrices $A_{2 \times 2},B_{2 \times 2},C_{2 \times 2}$, with their traces equal to one another $TrA=TrB=TrC$. Knowing that $AB+BC+CA=BA+CB+AC$, prove thtat there exists $a\in \mathbb{C}$ such as $B=(1-a)A+aC$.

I tried applying Hamilton Caylay $A^{2}-Tr(A)A+detAI_{2}=O_{2}$, the characteristic polynomial $det(xI_{2}-A)=x^{2}-Tr(A)x+detA$ and also $det(A+xB)=detA+(Tr(A)Tr(B)-Tr(AB))x+detBx^{2}$.
Moreover, I attempted to rearange $AB-BA+BC-CB+CA-AC=O_{2}$ and $B-A=a(C-A)$.

I think I am close but I can't find how to prove it. Can you give me some help? Thank you

Comment: This might be a weird idea, but you could think of the matrices as points in a 4-dimensional space and see if the given conditions essentially amount to imposing three (linear) constraints on the matrices - this would mean that they all lie on a straight line in that 4-d space, which would vindicate being able to write B like that (it's like a section formula)

Comment: yes I guess it could work, but i has to be related to eigenvalues, determinants and formulas with them. That's the level that this problem is for. Thank you for the ideea, I will try to solve it that way if I can't figure another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $X=B-A$ and $Y=C-A$. Use the condition $AB+BC+CA=BA+CB+AC$ to show that $X$ and $Y$ commute. Since $A,B$ and $C$ are three distinct matrices of the same trace, $X$ and $Y$ must be two distinct, nonzero, and traceless $2\times2$ matrices. By considering the possible Jordan forms of $Y$, show that the only nonzero *traceless* matrices $X$ that commute with $Y$ are those nonzero scalar multiples of $Y$. Hence $X=aY$ for some scalar $a$ and $B-A=a(C-A)$.

Comment: thank you a lot. I managed to solve it using this hint! I was not used to the Jordan normal, but I learned how write it.